# Select text following last $ in an expression?

Tags: php, regex

I am using a regular expression to extract the price on the right from the following HTML:

```
<p class="pricing ats-product-price"><em class="old_price">$99.99</em>$94.99</p>
```

Using preg match in PHP:

```
preg_match_all('!<p class="pricing ats-product-price"><em class="old_price">.*?<\/em>(.*?)<\/p>!', $output, $prices);
```

Except, I noticed that sometimes the HTML doesn't include an old price. So sometimes the HTML looks like this:

```
<p class="pricing ats-product-price">$129.99</p>
```

It seems like my goal should be to extract the *last* price from the expression, or in other words the text that directly follows after the last question mark and before the `</p>`. This sort of expression is way out of my league though - hoping for some help here. Thanks.

Comment: don't parse html with regex ...just don't

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Any particular reason? I've tried using a couple of different options and I found it the quickest to develop with. What would you recommend using?

Comment: *the quickest* doesn't mean "the best". XML/HTML parsers is the only way for xml/html data

Comment: Make the old price optional `<p class="pricing ats-product-price">(?:<em class="old_price">.*?<\/em>)?(.*?)<\/p>` Thatway, it consumes it if there, leaving just the _last_ price.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression *in combination* with a parser:

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
    <p class="pricing ats-product-price">
        <em class="old_price">$99.99</em>
        $94.99
    </p>
    <p class="pricing ats-product-price">$129.99</p>
DATA;

# set up the dom
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

# set up the xpath
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$regex = '~\$\d+[\d.]*\b\s*\Z~';
foreach ($xpath->query("//p") as $line) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $line->nodeValue, $match)) {
        echo $match[0] . "\n";
    }
}
```

This yields

```
$129.99
$129.99
```

---

The snippet sets up the `DOM`, queries it for `p` tags and searches for the last price within.
See [**a demo for the expression on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/vLeiMa/1).

Comment: I think it isn't important to check how looks like the nodeValue with a pattern. Here the main goal is to return the old price when it exists or the price when the old price doesn't exist. You can do it with an XPath query, for example: `//p[./@class[contains(.,"pricing") and contains(.,"ats-product-price")]]/em[contains(@class,"old_price")] | //p[./@class[contains(.,"pricing") and contains(.,"ats-product-price")]][not(./em)]`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: I find mine slightly more readable, admittedly :) But you are right, one could do without a regular expression here.

Comment: Also, be careful with the option `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED`, when the document doesn't have a root element, libxml transforms something like `<p></p><p></p>` into `<p><p></p></p>` (it uses the first element and moves silently the closing `</p>` to the end to have a root element).